P=I-B ,where P is Idempotent.Then how to prove B is idempotent?
Converse of the Proof already exist,but show me how to prove it other way round !
show that how to prove $B$ as Idempotent,if $I$ is Idempotent where $P=I-B$.

Yes, otherwise most probably, this will be deleted soon for the same reason.

As, $P = I - B$, is idempodent then $P^2 = (I - B)^2 = I - 2B + B^2 = P = I - B \implies B^2 = B.$
